# iOS Tab Bar App with UITableViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitabbarcontroller

I want to add Tabbar to my application. Tabbar is not visible even though I have already added the codes. How do I add `AppDelegate` if I can't add it from `UITableViewController`? What had I better do?

```
class MainTableViewController: UITableViewController {

     private func tabbar() {
            let tabBarController = FluidTabBarController()
            tabBarController.tabBar.tintColor = UIColor(red: 0.2431372549, green: 0.4235294118, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
            let viewControllers = [
                ("News", #imageLiteral(resourceName: "output-onlinepngtools")),

                ].map(createSampleViewController)
            tabBarController.setViewControllers(viewControllers, animated: true)

        }

        private func createSampleViewController(title: String, icon: UIImage) -> UIViewController {
            let viewController = UIViewController()
            viewController.view.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.9490196078, green: 0.9529411765, blue: 0.968627451, alpha: 1)
            let item = FluidTabBarItem(title: title, image: icon, tag: 0)
            item.imageColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.7960784314, green: 0.8078431373, blue: 0.8588235294, alpha: 1)
            viewController.tabBarItem = item
            return viewController
        }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            tabbar()
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that's what you asked for, just embed your ViewController in the `UITabBarController`

[image: storyboard]

If you want to do this programatically you need to create your `UITabBarController` and add your custom view controllers. in your case the `FirstViewController` is gonna be a `UITableViewController`

```
class MyUITabBarController: UITabBarController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let firstViewController = FirstViewController()

        firstViewController.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(tabBarSystemItem: .search, tag: 0)

        let secondViewController = SecondViewController()

        secondViewController.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(tabBarSystemItem: .more, tag: 1)

        let tabBarList = [firstViewController, secondViewController]

        viewControllers = tabBarList
    }
}
```

Then instantiate your `UITabBarController` in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

```
window?.rootViewController = MyUITabBarController()
window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

and the job is done!

Comment: How do I do it as a code? I'm not using Storyboard.

Comment: Can't I use uitabbarcontroller in uitableviewcontroller?

Comment: Sorry you don't need to extend. You need to create an instance of UITabbarController and add your tableViewController to your insance's viewcontrollers. And show tabbarController on top instead of your tableViewController.